# Why my data not getting exported to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, export-to-excel

I am having this code...

```
public void ExportClientsListToExcel()
{
    var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

    grid.DataSource = db.GetCompleteEmpReport();

    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Exported_Diners.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.End();

}
```

where in I am getting the stored procedure data,populating the grid and then getting the Exported to Excel.It does not give me any error but not getting the required Exported file.Where I have gone wrong?

I am getting the required data in sw.ToString() part but not getting exported.
I am calling that method by ajax Post call on the client side and have this code

```
  $("#btnExport").click(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/ExportClientsListToExcel',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (status) {
                alert();
            },
        });
    });
```

The alert() popup is also coming.

Comment: Have you already debugged the code?

Comment: yea..was not getting any error

Comment: but not getting export

Comment: try removing Response.End()

Comment: tried....not getting solved though

Comment: Your code doesn't generate an Excel file at all. You are simply sending an HTML table with the wrong extension. Instead of trying to hack Excel exporting, use a library like EPPlus to create a real Excel file

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I am very new to this sir, could you please provide me any example.

Comment: I already did. Just check the duplicate question. There are a *lot* of similar questions in SO which you can easily find by searching